# HID devices for virtual machines

Tags: python, bots, virtual-machine, emulation, hid

I've been playing some crypto games and to boost my farming I've been using a bot that controls the mouse to farm my resources.

The bot is built in python and it uses the main hid device to work.

I've been thinking in using VM's to run the bots with the games, but it made me run into a question.

Is it possible to emulate a virtual mouse cursor or something similar to run inside the VM?
This way i wouldn't need to let mt pc sitting farming and not utilizing it and the vm would run the bot and the virtual mouse to farm my cryptos.

Is it possible to emulate HID devices for VMs?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pyautogui` to simulate mouse clicks. You can run the python script inside the VM and then let it run in the background and you can freely use the mouse outside VM.

Usage is simple

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.click(100, 100)
```

To know more about mouse functions refer to the docs https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html